# lein-droid not detecting cider nrepl

Tags: android, clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to setup a lein-droid project, everything works until I'm trying to connect to `localhost:9999`, it said `cider-nrepl` is uninstalled when in fact I have it working with a non-lein-droid project.

Here's my `project.clj`:

```
(defproject events/events "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: Android project description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}

  :global-vars {*warn-on-reflection* true}

  :source-paths ["src/clojure" "src"]
  :java-source-paths ["src/java"]
  :javac-options ["-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "-Xlint:-options"]
  :plugins [[lein-droid "0.3.0-beta4"]]

  :dependencies [[org.clojure-android/clojure "1.7.0-alpha3" :use-resources true]
                 [neko/neko "3.1.0-preview2"]]
  :profiles {:default [:dev]

             :dev
             [:android-common :android-user
              {:dependencies [[org.clojure-android/tools.nrepl "0.2.6"]]
               :target-path "target/debug"
               :android {:aot :all-with-unused
                         :rename-manifest-package "org.stuff.events.debug"
                         :manifest-options {:app-name "EventsListing - debug"}}}]
             :release
             [;; :android-common
              {:target-path "target/release"
               :android
               { ;; Specify the path to your private keystore
                ;; and the the alias of the key you want to
                ;; sign APKs with.
                ;; :keystore-path "/home/user/.android/private.keystore"
                ;; :key-alias "mykeyalias"

                :ignore-log-priority [:debug :verbose]
                :aot :all
                :build-type :release}}]}

  :android {;; Specify the path to the Android SDK directory.
            ;; :sdk-path "/home/user/path/to/android-sdk/"

            ;; Try increasing this value if dexer fails with
            ;; OutOfMemoryException. Set the value according to your
            ;; available RAM.
            :dex-opts ["-JXmx4096M"]

            ;; If previous option didn't work, uncomment this as well.
            ;; :force-dex-optimize true

            :target-version "21"
            :aot-exclude-ns ["clojure.parallel" "clojure.core.reducers"
                             "cljs-tooling.complete" "cljs-tooling.info"
                             "cljs-tooling.util.analysis" "cljs-tooling.util.misc"
                             "cider.nrepl" "cider-nrepl.plugin"]})
```

And here's my `profiles.clj`

```
{:user {:plugins [[jonase/eastwood "0.1.4"]
                  [lein-ancient "0.5.5"]
                  [lein-kibit "0.0.8"]
                  [lein-bikeshed "0.1.8"]
                  [cider/cider-nrepl "0.7.0"]
                  [lein-try "0.4.3"]
                  [ice/lein-template "0.1.3"]
                  [lein-light-nrepl "0.1.0"]
                  [lein-droid "0.3.0-beta4"]]
        :android {:sdk-path "/home/faris/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk"
                  ;; :dependencies [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.7.0"]]
                  }}
 :android-common {:android {:sdk-path "/home/faris/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk"}}
 :android-user {:dependencies [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.7.0"]]
                ;; :android {:sdk-path "/home/faris/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk"
                ;;           :aot-exclude-ns ["cider.nrepl.middleware.util.java.parser"
                ;;                            "cider.nrepl" "cider-nrepl.plugin"]}
                :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware
                              [cider.nrepl.middleware.complete/wrap-complete
                               cider.nrepl.middleware.inspect/wrap-inspect
                               cider.nrepl.middleware.stacktrace/wrap-stacktrace
                               cider.nrepl.middleware.macroexpand/wrap-macroexpand
                               cider.nrepl.middleware.trace/wrap-trace
                               cider.nrepl.middleware.undef/wrap-undef]}}}
```